# Avacado leaves browning, new leaves wilting

Tags: indoors, wilting

Ive been growing three avacados from pit for about 2 years indoors, they’ve done well but recently two have developed brown spots in between the “veins” one I decided to replace with a different plant once all the leaves died but now it’s happening to my favorite one. I live in Virginia and I’ve moved them outside, I water them only when the top of the soil feels dry, I did recently repot them in bigger pots, once browning stared I moved them outside but no change is seen. The new leaves sprouting are also turning black and wilting, I will attach pictures, please help! enter image description here[image]